# Invoking RunCukeTest with @ExtendedCucumberOptions throwing Initialization Error

Tags: cucumber

**Environment - Cucumber V. 4.0.0 | Selenium V.3.8.1 | JUnit V.4.12 | cucumber-runner & cucumber-report-generator 1.3.3**

First time i am trying to implement @ExtendedCucumberOptions so that i can run failed test case again. Getting initialization error -

[image]

More Info about Error -

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    cucumber/runtime/ExtendedRuntime.runStep(Ljava/lang/String;Lgherkin/formatter/model/Step;Lgherkin/formatter/Reporter;Lgherkin/I18n;)V @94: invokeinterface
  Reason:
    Type 'cucumber/runtime/StepDefinitionMatch' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'gherkin/formatter/model/Match'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @94
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'cucumber/runtime/ExtendedRuntime', 'java/lang/String', 'gherkin/formatter/model/Step', 'gherkin/formatter/Reporter', 'gherkin/I18n', 'cucumber/runtime/StepDefinitionMatch' }
    stack: { 'gherkin/formatter/Reporter', 'cucumber/runtime/StepDefinitionMatch' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab6 0070 2b2c 1904 b900 6504 003a 05a7
    0x0000010: 0047 3a06 2d19 06b6 0072 03b9 0073 0200
    0x0000020: c000 52b9 0074 0200 bb00 5059 1260 09b8
    0x0000030: 0059 1906 b200 5ab7 005b 3a07 2d19 07b9
    0x0000040: 0075 0200 2a19 07b7 0076 2a19 06b6 0061
    0x0000050: 2a04 b500 0cb1 1905 c600 0e2d 1905 b900
    0x0000060: 7402 00a7 0022 2db2 0077 b900 7402 002d
    0x0000070: b200 78b9 0075 0200 2ab2 0078 b700 762a
    0x0000080: 04b5 000c b12a b400 14b6 004c 9900 082a
    0x0000090: 04b5 000c 2ab4 000c 9900 162a b200 79b7
    0x00000a0: 0076 2db2 0079 b900 7502 00a7 0114 1251
    0x00000b0: 3a06 013a 072a b400 15b9 0056 0100 1905
    0x00000c0: 1904 b600 6f2a b400 15b9 0058 0100 3708
    0x00000d0: bb00 5059 1906 1608 b800 5919 07b2 005a
    0x00000e0: b700 5b3a 0a2a 190a b700 762d 190a b900
    0x00000f0: 7502 00a7 00cc 3a08 1908 3a07 1260 3a06
    0x0000100: 2a19 08b6 0061 2ab4 0015 b900 5801 0037
    0x0000110: 08bb 0050 5919 0616 08b8 0059 1907 b200
    0x0000120: 5ab7 005b 3a0a 2a19 0ab7 0076 2d19 0ab9
    0x0000130: 0075 0200 a700 8b3a 0819 083a 0719 08b8
    0x0000140: 0045 9900 0a12 5f3a 06a7 0007 1260 3a06
    0x0000150: 2a19 08b6 0061 2a04 b500 0c2a b400 15b9
    0x0000160: 0058 0100 3708 bb00 5059 1906 1608 b800
    0x0000170: 5919 07b2 005a b700 5b3a 0a2a 190a b700
    0x0000180: 762d 190a b900 7502 00a7 0036 3a0b 2ab4
    0x0000190: 0015 b900 5801 0037 0cbb 0050 5919 0616
    0x00001a0: 0cb8 0059 1907 b200 5ab7 005b 3a0e 2a19
    0x00001b0: 0eb7 0076 2d19 0eb9 0075 0200 190b bfb1
    0x00001c0:                                        
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 15] => handler: 18
    bci [190, 197] => handler: 246
    bci [190, 197] => handler: 311
    bci [190, 197] => handler: 396
    bci [246, 262] => handler: 396
    bci [311, 347] => handler: 396
    bci [396, 398] => handler: 396
  Stackmap Table:
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@18,Object[#311])
    append_frame(@86,Object[#303])
    same_frame(@102)
    same_frame(@133)
    same_frame(@148)
    same_frame(@174)
    full_frame(@246,{Object[#194],Object[#277],Object[#302],Object[#275],Object[#312],Object[#303],Object[#277],Object[#278]},{Object[#313]})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_extended(@311,Object[#278])
    append_frame(@332,Object[#278])
    same_frame(@336)
    full_frame(@396,{Object[#194],Object[#277],Object[#302],Object[#275],Object[#312],Object[#303],Object[#277],Object[#278]},{Object[#278]})
    chop_frame(@447,2)

    at com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumber.createRuntime(ExtendedCucumber.java:93)
    at com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumber.<init>(ExtendedCucumber.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

First let me share my understanding on implementation, we have to add below 2 dependencies -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-report-generator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**I also added below 2 as i was under impression, these shall be added as well by doing some research on net.**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.28</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Below is RunCukeTest.java Class -**

```
@RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)
@ExtendedCucumberOptions(
        jsonReport = "target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
        retryCount = 3,
        detailedReport = true,
        detailedAggregatedReport = true,
        overviewReport = true,
        coverageReport = true,
        jsonUsageReport = "target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-usage.json",
        usageReport = false,
        toPDF = true,
       // excludeCoverageTags = {"@sanity" },
        includeCoverageTags = {"@regression" },
        outputFolder = "target/cucumber-reports/extended-report")

@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features/functional/",
                     glue = {"com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional" },
                   plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
                            "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-reports",
                            "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"},
                   tags = { "@regression" },
                   junit ={ "--step-notifications"},
                   strict = false,
                   dryRun = false,
               monochrome = true)

public class RunCukeTest {
}
```

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.jacksparrow.automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>TheDayAfterTomorrow</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</url>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <cucumberversion>4.0.0</cucumberversion>
        <selenium.version>3.8.1</selenium.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.12.0</assertj-core.version>
        <cucumberdatatableversion>1.1.12</cucumberdatatableversion>
        <webdrivermanager.version>3.0.0</webdrivermanager.version>
        <extent.report.version>3.1.1</extent.report.version>
        <extent-cucumber-adapter.version>1.0.5</extent-cucumber-adapter.version>
        <maven-surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven-surefire.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.8.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>2.22.1</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
        <maven.build.helper.plugin.version>3.0.0</maven.build.helper.plugin.version>
        <joda-time>2.5</joda-time>
        <mysql>5.1.6</mysql>
        <jackson-core>2.6.3</jackson-core>
        <common-db-utils>1.6</common-db-utils>
        <commons-io>2.6</commons-io>
        <commons-lang>3.4</commons-lang>
        <lombok>1.16.4</lombok>
        <slf4jVersion>1.7.7</slf4jVersion>
        <apache.poi.version>3.16</apache.poi.version>
        <generated.runner.directory>${project.build.directory}/parallel/runners</generated.runner.directory>
        <generated.feature.directory>${project.build.directory}/parallel/features</generated.feature.directory>
    </properties>

<dependencies>

<!-- ********************************()() IO.CUCUMBER & SELENIUM DEPENDENCIES ()()******************************** -->  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumberversion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumberversion}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumberversion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumberversion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumberdatatableversion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-report-generator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- ************************************()() EXTENT REPORT DEPENDENCY ()()******************************* -->      
<!--    <dependency> -->
<!--        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>4.0.9</version> -->
<!--    </dependency> -->

<!--    <dependency> -->
<!--        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>${extent.report.version}</version> -->
<!--    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>${extent-cucumber-adapter.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- *******************************()() CUCUMBER MAVEN REPORTING DEPENDENCY ()()***************************** -->      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- **************************************()() SLF4J DEPENDENCY ()()************************************ -->       
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
   </dependency>

<!-- ****************************************()() JSON DEPENDENCY ()()************************************** -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-cucumber4-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- **********************************()() JAVA MAIL API DEPENDENCY ()()************************************ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- **************************************()() LOG4J DEPENDENCY ()()*************************************** -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- ************************************()() POI & XML DEPENDENCY ()()************************************** -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.11-beta3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io}</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- ***************************************()() REPORTNG DEPENDENCY ()()********************************* -->  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-dep</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>   

<!-- ***************************************()() APPIUM DEPENDENCY ()()********************************* -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- *****************************************()() PDF DEPENDENCY ()()********************************** -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- ************************************()() ATUTestRecorder DEPENDENCY ()()**************************** -->       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.CA.ATU21</groupId>
        <artifactId>ATUTestRecorder</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ATUTestRecorder-2.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<!-- ************************************()() MAVEN COMPILER PLUGIN ()()*************************************** -->
<build>
    <plugins>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

<!-- ************************************()() MAVEN SUREFIRE PLUGIN ()()*************************************** -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>methods</parallel>
            <threadCount>1</threadCount>
            <reuserForks>false</reuserForks>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*RunCukeTest.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

<!-- ***********************************()() CLUECUMBER REPORT PLUGIN ()()*********************************** -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
        <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>reporting</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <sourceJsonReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}\cucumber-json</sourceJsonReportDirectory>
            <generatedHtmlReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}\cluecumber-report</generatedHtmlReportDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

<!-- ******************************()() MAVEN CUCUMBER HTML REPORT PLUGIN ()()******************************** -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>execution</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <projectName>TheDayAfterTomorrow</projectName>
                    <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-maven-report</outputDirectory>
                    <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-json</inputDirectory>
                    <jsonFiles>
                        <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                        <param>**/*.json</param>
                    </jsonFiles>
                    <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
                    <enableFlashCharts>true</enableFlashCharts>
                    <buildNumber>10.2.1</buildNumber>
                    <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
            <reportVersion>2.7.0</reportVersion>
            <allureDownloadUrl>https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip</allureDownloadUrl>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

What could be wrong here.

Comment: The `ExtendedCucumber` does not support Cucumber after 1.2.5. 

https://github.com/mkolisnyk/cucumber-reports/issues/196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now its clear @ExtendedCucumberOptions were supported till Cucumber V 1.2.5 and Someone working on Cucumber 4.0.0 or later of V 1.2.5 shall not use this option in case someone like to re-run their failed test cases.